# Can't add elements to my array within an asynchronous forEach loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

In my current project, using Firebase as backend, I have a dedicated function to remove inactive users upon certain criteria (not relevant for this question).

Within my Firebase function, I have this internal function that is used to fetch the inactive users, but it always returns an empty array:

```
async function getInactiveUsers(users: any[], nextPageToken?: any): Promise<any> {
    const getUsers: any = await admin.auth().listUsers(1000, nextPageToken);
    const threeMonthsAgo = new Date(Date.now())
    threeMonthsAgo.setMonth(threeMonthsAgo.getMonth() - 3)   
    const inactiveThreeMonthsUsers: any = getUsers.users.filter((user: any) => 
        Date.parse(user.metadata.lastSignInTime) < threeMonthsAgo.getTime()
    );  
    if(inactiveThreeMonthsUsers.length > 0){
        inactiveThreeMonthsUsers.forEach(async (user: any) => {
            const UserDataRef = admin.firestore().collection('Collection').doc(user.uid);
            const UserDataGet = await UserDataRef.get();
            const UserData: any = UserDataGet.data();
            if((UserData.firstCriteria < 1) && (UserData.secondCriteria === 0)){
                users.push(user.uid);
            }
        });       
        if (getUsers.pageToken) {
            return getInactiveUsers(users, getUsers.pageToken);
        }      
        return users;
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}
```

I have loged the users array right after the push method method, like that :

```
if((UserData.firstCriteria < 1) && (UserData.secondCriteria === 0)){
    users.push(user.uid);
    console.log("users: " + users)
}
```

And that `console.log` displays the contents with the data inside the array, but the function still returns an empty array.

I added a value in the array before the `forEach`:

```
async function getInactiveUsers(users: any[], nextPageToken?: any): Promise<any> {
    users.push("test");
    // ...the rest of the code
}
```

And this item is returned. So that made me think that the `forEach` loop appends a copy of the array.

I also tried to store the user argument in a new array, declared at the top of this function, then append it with the `push()` method. But also that doesn't work.

What is wrong with my approach?

Comment: Sorry maybe it's a lack of understand on my side, but I thought my getUsers awaits the list of users. I mean I have `const getUsers: any = await admin.auth().listUsers(1000, nextPageToken);`

For the rest generally my code editor tells me if there is a bad Promise handling.
It's no present in my question but when I call this function I awaits it.

My code is inspired from what is provided by Firebase on their Github

https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/delete-unused-accounts-cron/functions/index.js

Comment: No you are right, there is no problem there. I misread the code. The problem is in the `forEach` which makes all iterations without waiting. The `await` in the callback only makes the callback wait, but not `forEach`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `forEach` loop will run synchronously, while the `async` callback you pass to it will partly run asynchronously (the part after `await`).

To make the loop iterations wait on the asynchronous code before going to the next iteration, use a `for` loop.

```
for (let user of inactiveThreeMonthsUsers) { .... await .... }
```

Comment: Thank you, indeed replacing my `forEach` by a `for` like you showed did the trick.